# VirtualHost problem

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

this is my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www/domain2
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong when the browser always shows first entry - /home/www/domain1?

Thanks,
Etam.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

a. You're missing the NameVirtualHosts settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530418/wamp-server-multiple-virtual-hosts-are-not-working-on-windows/2530518#2530518

or

b. the domain you're visiting matches domain1.com, or it doesn't match either (apache will default to the first one.)

or

c. the method/client you're using to visit the web page doesn't send the appropriate headers for the server name ('ancient' clients per the apache docs)

Comment: Begin from C point!